# does 「なう」have effeminate connotations?

Tags: slang, loanwords, internet-slang, feminine-speech

I often get text messages from people who use the twitter-derived slang 「なう」 to mean "now." As in 「電車なう」meaning "(I am on the) train now."

However, these mainly come from women, and one gay dude. Is that just a coincidence, or does using this term actually have some feminine/effeminate connotation, like appending わ for emphasis (e.g. 「疲れたわ〜」)?

Comment: I have never heard that the Twitter slang “なう” has any feminine (or effeminate) connotations.  I am not a Twitter user, and people who are using Twitter are better qualified to answer the question.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto - the usage is not limited to Twitter.  OP is saying it may have originated in Twitter because of the character limit.  Anyway, no, I don't believe it has effeminate connotations.  Plenty of straight guys I know use it all the time.

Comment: @istrasci: not a twitter user either, but I must admit I'm confused how なう would help with character limit... :-| Any way you look at it, 今 or いま is same length or shorter.

Comment: @istrasci: I see.  I did not know that なう is used outside Twitter.  (I do not live in Japan and I do not receive SMS messages in Japanese, which may explain my ignorance on this.)  Anyway the main point of my previous comment stands: I am not very qualified to answer this question! :)

Comment: Well, I read it on mixi and facebook too, but mostly in titles and short comments, like "running naked in Shinjukuなう" (even with some English sentences, in fact).

Comment: @Dave: Nor do I use Twitter (FB people use it just as much) and I share your confusion about the point of it.  I personally think it's just a way they (whoever uses it) try to sound modern and maybe "international".  I find it annoying, myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. It does not have any feminine connotations.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that girls and gay men might be more likely to use it, because it is a bit of a cute/silly thing (being a sort of silly borrowing from English, for some reason written in hiragana rather than katakana).